# Jquery ajax method undefined

Tags: ajax, jquery

So my problem is that data returned in success method is undefined...

**Here is my jquery code:**

```
  $('document').ready(function(){



      $('#save').click(function() {

      var dataString = $("#stepform").serialize();

      $.ajax({
     url: "<?php echo base_url();?>create/save/<?php echo $row->id; ?>",
     type: 'POST',
     data: dataString,
     success:function(response){

        alert(response.status);

     }
    });//end ajax

    return false;
});//end click

  }); // end document ready
```

**And php code:**

```
$serverResponse["status"] = 'it worked';
echo json_encode($serverResponse);
```

And all i'm getting from response.status is 'undefined'... I just can't make it work! Any ideas what i'm doing wrong?

**-------------EDIT-------------**

Finally i have managed to find a solution to invalid json response. If you are using codeigniter you must write exit() after json_encode. Something like this:

```
exit(json_encode($yourarray));
```

If you just echo it then it gives a parse error.

Comment: do you create your php array somewhere

Answer (score 1):

jQuery may not be properly guessing that you are returning JSON.  Set the `dataType: "json"` property on the `$.ajax` argument object, or add

```
header("Content-type: application/json");
```

to your PHP script before emission, or both.

Comment: @VxsdfsdfAzcxzc in that case you may have either an error/notice/warning in your PHP code or you are printing out something other than just the JSON.  Do you get an error in the console?

Comment: When i view my request sent with chrome developer tools i see it says "status ok code 200" and in preview tab it says "{"status":"it worked"}" No error in console.

Comment: @VxsdfsdfAzcxzc what if you add the `error` property and give it a callback?  Or `complete`?

Comment: Yup error function fires... And after that complete also fires. Also with dataType="json" form data doesn't get passed.

Comment: @VxsdfsdfAzcxzc okay it's great that it fires, but what is the error message?

Comment: If i alert(response.status) output is "200"

Comment: @VxsdfsdfAzcxzc then it seems like the error is due to invalid JSON.